# I need to be able to click buttons multiple times in my Javascript/html/css code, however, the code stops working after clicking a button once

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple game where the user fights with an enemy. The user is given 4 choices, or 4 buttons. If the user chooses one of the 4, a random number is generated to determine whether the user or the enemy goes first, then a number is generated again to determine a number (which equals to a specific damage point). After the damage is determined, it is added to a progress bar which is my HP bar. Pressing the button works only once, and after that, it won't do damage anymore.

attackorder determines who attacks first, start() starts the attack, and  enemyAttack() generates enemy damage.

```js
var userDamage, monsterDamage = 0;
var move = 0;
var priority;
var randomNum = 0;
var someoneIsAlive = true;

    attackMove1.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        attackOrder();
        move = 1;

    });
    attackMove2.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        attackOrder();
        move = 2;

    });
    attackMove3.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        attackOrder();
        move = 3;

    });
    attackMove4.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        attackOrder();
        move = 4;
    });
    


function attackOrder(){
    let froakieSpeed = Math.floor((Math.random()* 62));
    let goomySpeed = Math.floor((Math.random()* 55));
    if (froakieSpeed > goomySpeed)
       {
        priority = "froakie";
       } 
    else {
        priority = "goomy"
        if (move = 1){priority = "froakie"};
    }
    start();
}
    
function start(){
        if (priority = "froakie"){
            userAttack();
            enemyAttack();
        } else {
            enemyAttack();
            userAttack();
        }   
}
var poisonDamage;
/*
Quick Attack (unconditionally attacks first), 
Watergun, 
Lick (afflicts poison), 
Pound  
*/
function userAttack(){
    randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6));
    switch(randomNum){
        case 0:
            userDamage = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            userDamage = 10;
            break;
        case 2:
            userDamage = 10;
            break;
        case 3:
            userDamage = 15;
            break;
        case 4:
            userDamage = 15;
            break;
        case 5:
            userDamage = 20;
            break;
        case 6:
            userDamage = 40;
            break;        
    }
    if (move = 3){
        poisonStatus();   
    } 

    if (poisonStatus = true){
        userDamage += 5;
    }
    let monsterHP = document.getElementById("monsterHP")
    monsterHP.value += userDamage;
    if (monsterHP.value >= 100){
        alert("You Win!");
    }
}

function enemyAttack(){
        randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6));
    switch(randomNum){
        case 0:
            monsterDamage = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            monsterDamage = 10;
            break;
        case 2:
            monsterDamage = 10;
            break;
        case 3:
            monsterDamage = 15;
            break;
        case 4:
            monsterDamage = 15;
            break;
        case 5:
            monsterDamage = 20;
            break;
        case 6:
            monsterDamage = 40;
            break; 

    }
    let userHP = document.getElementById("userHP")
    userHP.value += monsterDamage;

    if (userHP.value >= 100){
        alert("You Lose! :(");
    }
}

var poisonBreak;
function poisonStatus(){
    poisonBreak = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2 ));
    if (poisonBreak = 2){
        poisonDamage = false;
    } else {
        poisonDamage = true;
    }   
}

userDamage, monsterDamage = 0;
randomNum = 0;
move = 0;
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #449C6A;
  }
  
progress {
    width: 300px;
    height : 25px;
    border: 2px solid #FFE5B4;
    
 }
 progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background-color: green;
 }
 progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-color: red;
 }

 body{
    overflow:hidden;
 }

 .container{
    width: 95%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: end;
    justify-content: center;
        /*Delete after done*/
    border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .actions{
    width: 370px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 15px 15px 20px 20px;
    align-items: end;
    justify-content: center;
    position: static;
        /*Delete after done*/
    border: 1px solid black;
  }


.userMove{
    width: 95%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: white(0, 0, 0);
}

.userMove:hover{background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.514);}

#userHP{
    position:fixed;
    top:72%;
    left:26.5%;
  
}
#monsterHP{
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:57%;
  
}

img.userSprite{
    width: 9%;
    height: auto;
}

img.enemySprite{
    width: 13%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Head -->
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Mon Fight!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
        body {
          background-image: url('battleBackground.png');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: 50% 1%;
        }
        </style>
        
  </head>
<!-- Body -->
<body> 
    <div class="container">
<!-- moves -->        
        <div class="actions">
            <button id = "attackMove1" class="userMove">Quick Attack</button>
            <button id = "attackMove2" class="userMove">Water Gun</button>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button id = "attackMove3" class="userMove">Lick</button>
            <button id = "attackMove4" class="userMove">Pound</button>
        </div>
<!-- user character -->
        <div class="userCharacter">
            <img class="userSprite" src="https://www.pokencyclopedia.info/sprites/3ds/ani-b_6/3a-b__656__xy.gif" style = "position: absolute; left: 30%; top:50%">
            <progress id = "userHP" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>       
<!-- enemy character-->        
        <div class="monsterCharacter">
            <img class="enemySprite" src="https://pa1.aminoapps.com/6202/8b1a1344c2f3c1e5d8251d998f8e9b63e193c81f_hq.gif" style = "position: absolute; left: 58%; top:27%">
            <progress id = "monsterHP" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <script src="script.js"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```

I have 4 event listeners for each button, which I expected to list every click to be counted as an event, however, as the title states, it only works for the first move. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please include the HTML and turn the whole thing into a runnable snippet (use the `<>` icon) that demonstrates the issue right here on this page?

Comment: @CherryDT hello, I edited it to be a runnable code snippet. Hopefully nintendo doesn't chase me, lol. This is for a class.

Comment: After being able to see the error (I don't see it in vscode), I actually found the cause of the problem. it's the poison section of my code. The code now works past the first move.

Comment: "After being able to see the error (I don't see it in vscode)" - then you are probably looking in the wrong place, you need to look in your browser's devtools (what you get when you press F12 in the browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `posonStatus` function and then you are overwriting that function with a boolean `true`:

```
    if (poisonStatus = true){
        userDamage += 5;
    }
```

I'm guessing you meant to check if `poisonDamage` is true:

```
    if (poisonDamage == true){
        userDamage += 5;
    }
```

In fact, throughout the code you are using assignment operator (`=`) in the if conditions instead of comparison operator (`==` or `===`)

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for the help! this solved it. It's my first time coding in javascript so I kind of missed it.